# What characters can be identified in the Obi-Wan Kenobi trailer?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

The official teaser trailer for upcoming Obi-Wan Kenobi series on Disney+ has been released and we are treated to some familiar faces and some new ones.

However, I suspect some of these characters that I think are new have been seen or mentioned in other Star Wars properties. So which ones can be identify using prior works?

To be concise I am asking about the following characters:

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image: List item]
4. [image: List item]

The others like Obi-wan himself, Owen Lars, young Luke, etc. I have worked out on my own (taps forehead).

May the Fourth be with you!

Comment: And with youtube ;)

Comment: 4th character is obviously Spock. Wait, wrong franchise.

Comment: I can definitely see old Ben Kenobi in there, maybe that's who they mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first 3 are all Inquisitors, dark side individuals who hunted down the remaining Jedi after Order 66. We've mainly seen them in *Star Wars Rebels* and other content set at the same time such as the *Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order* game.

The first one is the [Grand Inquisitor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Inquisitor#Appearances), the highest ranking of them and the group's leader.

[image: Full body shot of the Grand Inquisitor with his dual lightsaber extended]

The third looks to probably be the [Fifth Brother](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fifth_Brother), at least that's what most places are reporting and he does look somewhat similar, costume-wise at least.

[image: Close up of the Fifth Brother's face]

The second character here is the [Third Sister](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Third_Sister) but is also known as Reva. She is a new character for this series as far as I'm aware.

The fourth here is [Haja Estree](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Haja_Estree), he is a contact that Obi-Wan meets on Daiyu believing him to be a Jedi. In fact Haja is a con artist pretending to be a Jedi to trick people out of money.